# Append a char at the end of each word using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a RegEx (Java) which will append **'~'** char after end of each word.
My requirement is:

1. Append ~ at the end of each word
2. If word has any special char in it, then do not append '~'.
3. If there are multiple whitespaces, it should be trim to single whitespace.

Please have a look on my example below :

```
Input: Hello World   How* A1e Y?u
Output: Hello~ World~ How* A1e~ Y?u
```

I took help from forum and could achieve it but I am not able to achieve #2.
My code snippet:

```
pattern = ([^\\s][a-zA-Z0-9])(\\s|$);
pattern.matcher(searchTerm).replaceAll("$1~$2");
```

How can I skip append operation if word has any special char?
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you required to use regex?

Comment: Try `searchTerm.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)\\w++(?!\\S)", "$0~")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its not working. ~ gets appended to only first word of the sentence.
Not to rest of the words.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/6BX5jK, output is `Hello~ World~   How* A1e~ Y?u`. But after a closer look, you probably want `searchTerm.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)\\w++(?!\\S)", "$0~").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim()`. See https://ideone.com/N2uIVO

Comment: Ahh, I will try to run a Java program instead, i was checking it on https://regex101.com/.
Thanks a lot Wiktor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot its working fine. Is it possible to provide whitelist of special char which are allowed. If word has +, - then we should append a word.

Comment: @Joe You'd need something like `"(?<!\\S)[\\w+-]++(?!\\S)"`, or `"(?<!\\S)\\w+(?:[+-]\\w+)*(?!\\S)"`, but this is quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
searchTerm = searchTerm.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)\\w++(?!\\S)", "$0~").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/N2uIVO)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind making sure there is either a whitespace or start of string right before the current location
- `\w++` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead making sure there is either a whitespace or start of string right after the current location.

The `$0` is the whole match value.

The `.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")` (for regular spaces, just replace `\\s` with a space) part "shrinks" any two or more whitespace characters to a single space, and `.trim()` part trims the result from whitespace on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

**This might help:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello World   How* A1e Y?u word";
    String extraSpaceInput = String.format(" %s ", input.replaceAll("\\s+", "  "));
    // Wanted output: Output: Hello~ World~ How* A1e~ Y?u word

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s");
    String output = pattern.matcher(extraSpaceInput).replaceAll("$1~ ");
    String cleanedUpOutput = output.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();

    // My output: "Hello~ World~ How* A1e~ Y?u word~"
    System.out.println("My output: \"" + cleanedUpOutput + "\"");
}
```